# How can I get all facets information in one request when using BestBuy Products API?

Tags: rest, best-buy-api

In order to build a filter bar for my website, I want to have a summary of products' details which is provided in facet attribute in Bestbuy API. There are a few facets that the details can be summarized by them such as Color, Shipping Cost, Manufacturer and so on.
For example, if you search for "desk", and the facet is set to "color", the respond of this request would show the top 5 colors that these desks are in.
The problem is that I cannot request to see the summary of details for all of these facets at once.

My Request should be in the form of https://api.bestbuy.com/v1/products((search=desk))?apiKey=BLAHBLAH&facet=color,3&format=json .

The response will contain the following list.

```
"facets": {
    "color": {
      "black": 609,
      "white": 93,
      "space gray": 71
    }
  }
```

How should I get all other facets in the same response?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Bestbuy doesn't provide this ability to get all facets at once.